# php code for checking whether a div is clicked or not

Tags: php, html

Can anyone help me .I need php code for checking whether a div is clicked or not.

like,

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) { }
```

But instead of submit button i  need a div ...
anyone help me please

thanks

Comment: A div? Do you mean checkbox or something else?

Comment: This will require client side scripting with event handlers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need JavaScript for this as PHP doesn't access the DOM if I'm reading your question correctly.  I would recommend you add jQuery lib to your page as it's simpler to add click event to a DIV, otherwise you have to add an event listener in javascript yourself for click events on the DIV.

jQuery:  http://api.jquery.com/click/

DIY: http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-122993.html

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell if you want a div to be treated as a form element, like a checkbox, or if you want to use a div to submit a form.

Using it as a form element has been explained by Stano, if you want the div to submit a form, you really should just use a submit button. If you want to use an image instead of a button, using `<input type="image"...>` will function as a submit button.

If you really need to use a div to submit the form, you will need javascript. Something like this, we take a form named "bald" and when you click the div, the form "bald" is submitted as if you pressed a submit button.

```
<form name="bald" action="somefile.php">
    <div onclick="bald.submit();">Click here to submit</div>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP can't tell you if a div has been clicked as php only works on the Server.  For this you need javascript.

[jquery](http://jquery.com/) makes something like this very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Can't quite imagine what can be this test good for, but you can use javascript like this:

```html
<div id="clickable_div" onclick="document.getElementById('divclicked').value='YES'"> SOMETHING </div>
```

in your form

```html
<input type="hidden" id="divclicked" name="divclicked" value="NO"/>
```

and in php

```php
if ($_POST['divclicked']=='YES') {...} else {...}
```