# Divs/spans as input type with $_POST information which of them was clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to create rating system, but instead of using radio input types I want to use custom divs/spans (containing fontello icons). Clicking on them should initialize post method like:

```
if (isset($_POST['span1'])){
/*send to database that user voted 1/5*/
}
if (isset($_POST['span2'])){
/*send to database that user voted 2/5*/
}
```

etc.

I found among others [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492797/php-code-for-checking-whether-a-div-is-clicked-or-not), hovewer it doesn't inform PHP which element was clicked. How can I achieve that?

My voting "template":

```
<form name="bald" method = "post">
    <span class="ico_style" onclick="bald.submit();" name = "span1">ICO</span>
    <span class="ico_style" onclick="bald.submit();" name = "span2">ICO</span>
    <span class="ico_style" onclick="bald.submit();" name = "span3">ICO</span>
    <span class="ico_style" onclick="bald.submit();" name = "span4">ICO</span>
    <span class="ico_style" onclick="bald.submit();" name = "span5">ICO</span>
</form>
```

Comment: use radio buttons man spans are NOT input fields

Comment: what's wrong with radio buttons?

Comment: I said that i want it INSTEAD inpit types because I use custom fontello icons.

Comment: why not use custom fontello icons on the RADIO INPUTS ?

Comment: I didn't find a proper way to use customizable  fontello in radio input. Only in submit buttons, hovewer it didn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to suggest you to use the power of javascript. To pass a value you need a `input`, it can be hidden. With javascript you handle clicks on spans and pass the value to the hidden input (`rateInput` here).

```
<form method="post" class="rate-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="rate" value="" class="rate-input">
    <span class="ico_style" data-rate="1">ICO</span>
    <span class="ico_style" data-rate="2">ICO</span>
    <span class="ico_style" data-rate="3">ICO</span>
    <span class="ico_style" data-rate="4">ICO</span>
    <span class="ico_style" data-rate="5">ICO</span>
</form>

<script>
    function onRate() {
        var rateInput = document.querySelector('.rate-input');
        rateInput.value = this.getAttribute('data-rate');
        document.querySelector('.rate-form').submit();
    }
    var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.rate-form .ico_style');
    for (var i = 0; i< spans.length; i++) {
        spans[i].addEventListener("click", onRate, true);
    }
</script>
```

Server-side:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['rate'])){
    $rate = $_POST['rate'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If my I ask if I think right: '.rate-form.ico_style'  means to select all selectors from form method? I am not so familiar with js.

Comment: @Atex select all elements with `ico_style` class which have parent with `rate-form` class. The space between class names is essential.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. It works perfectly now with my icons. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> (madalin ivascu) is right use radio buttons but if you want to use span,
>   then
>   create an hidden input in the bottom of form, when user click on icon use jquery to save which one he choose inside that input and check for it in your php function

```
if (isset($_POST['name_of_input'])){

}
```